# Given that $f(t+\tau,x) = f(t,x)$. how do I prove that the solution of $x'=f(t,x)$ is defined in all $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^n}$ with $f$ a continuous function. Let $\tau>0$ such that $\forall(t,x) \in \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R^n}, f(t+\tau,x) = f(t,x)$. And we are given the fact that $f$ is Lipschitz for $x\in [0,\tau]\times\mathbb{R^n}$. Then, the following Cauchy problem, $x'=f(t,x), x(t_0)=x_0$ for some $(t_0,x_0)$.

Can I go from the fact that the function $f$ is periodical to prove that the solution $\phi$ can be defined in all $\mathbb{R}$? Because from what I understand $f$ is gonna be well defined for any time interval that measures "$\tau$". So it can be extended to any interval, therefore all $\mathbb{R}$.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!! Struggling a bit with ODE.

Comment: $f$ is globally $x$-Lipschitz, this is sufficient for the claim

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thank you! but could you please elaborate a bit on that? I fail to see why just the x-Lipschitz condition is sufficient to prove my claim.

Comment: With that $f$ is linearly bounded and thus any solution exponentially bounded. Thus there will be no excursions to infinity at finite time, the maximal domain of any solution is $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann oh okay I understand it now. tho how do I prove that $f$ is linearly bounded given the x-Lipschitz condition? I didn't know the Lipschitz condition could give us a bound for $f$

Comment: This only work with a global Lipschitz condition: $|f(t,x)|\le |f(t,0)|+|f(t,x)-f(t,0)|\le|f(t,0)|+L|x|$.